# xdotool uses --screen value from where?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm trying to figure out where the value for --screen comes from when using xdotool, I can't seem to locate the values with xrandr.

I'll paste below xrandr's output, but "HDMI-0" is actually "--screen 2" for xdotool and the "DP-0" is "--screen 0". My guess is that X is polling in the order of DP-0, DP-1, HDMI-0 then DVI-D-0... but I don't know where X is storing those associations (or even if that it's correct that X is polling like that).

Working example for "HDMI-0": xdotool mousemove --screen 2 50 50 click 1

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3600 x 3840, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1440x2560+2160+1200 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 596mm x 335mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    50.00  
   2560x1440     29.95* 
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x1280     59.91  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1360x765      60.00  
   1280x1440     59.90  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 connected 2160x3840+0+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```